# how to plot a value using plot.stepfun when y is not longer than x

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a step function using stepfun. This requires that the vector giving the heights of the function values between the x values is 1 longer than x. However, because of this requirement I am unable to plot the value corresponding to the last category in my data.

The heights are given by:

```
beta_dec=c(.0453196,-.0254566,-.0156608,-.0015202,-.0026819)
```

The x values by

```
temp=seq(8,20,by=3)
```

I get an error when I run the following saying

```
graph<-stepfun(temp,beta_dec,f=0)
```

> "Error in stepfun(temp, beta_dec, f = 0) : 'y' must be one longer than 'x'"

If I terminate the sequence at 17, it runs fine but the value corresponding to 20 is not plotted?

Comment: Thanks but I was able to sort this out!

Comment: perhaps then you could post your answer or accept one that helped you (or delete the question) to indicate you're no longer waiting on a response.

Answer (score 4):

Would this suffice?

```
plot(beta_dec ~ temp, type = "s")
```

The `type = "s"` is defined in `?plot.default` and means stairs or steps. The above call gives:

[image: type = "s"]

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `stepfun` needs y one longer than x is because if you have x knots, then you need x+1 values to fully define the function. So, if your knots are at 1,2,3, then you need to have values for *before 1*, between 1 and 2, between 2 and 3, and after 3, which add up to 4 values. Basically, you need to figure out what the value of your function before 8 is. For example, you could do:

```
# Notice I added a value in front of beta_dec. You should add the real value.
beta_dec=c(.0453196,.0453196,-.0254566,-.0156608,-.0015202,-.0026819) 
temp=seq(8,20,by=3)
graph<-stepfun(temp,beta_dec,f=0)
plot(graph)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me understand why this requirement is needed.However, I don't know the value before 8 and cannot know it. So there is any way around this? Can I make the graph begin at 8 somehow?